# How can I remove nvidia drivers?

Tags: 11.04, nvidia

Recently I installed Ubuntu 11.04 (32 bit) on my Core i5 750 with a GeForce 210 graphics card.

Unfortunately, it installs the nVidia drivers automatically, without any prompt (unlike in earlier versions).
This of causes a reboot to a command line shell.
I can't even "reinstall", as the install mechanism itself brings the driver on-board my system.

How could I fix this?

Comment: so, how about uninstalling the nvidia drivers and removing your xorg.conf file? there are also notes on `blacklist`'ing `nouveau` out there -- is that what you are really looking for?

Comment: Which drivers are installed? Proprietary or free? I can't imagine it would automatically install proprietary drivers.

Comment: why 32-bit? why not 64?

Comment: @nik: I'm looking for the system to work - as to how, I couldn't care less.

Comment: @dv3500ea: So I understand.

Comment: @Alvar: Why not 32? I'm a bit shy as to the usage of 64, as it is not the recommended version...

Comment: @dv3500ea IIRC the Nvidia drivers are installed when ticking that proprietary software checkbox thingy in the installer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove nVidia driver and go back to Nouveau](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau)

Answer (score 8):

- When booting the system, press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to make the GRUB menu appear.
- In the GRUB menu select the *(recovery mode)* entry and let the system boot.
- You will be presented with another menu, scroll down and select *Drop to root shell prompt*.
- Recovery Console must first be made Read/Write.
- Run the following commands:

  ```
  mount -n -o remount,rw /
  apt-get purge nvidia-current
  rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
  reboot now
  ```