# Ubuntu stuck in low resolution after UNinstalling / disabling NVidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution, uninstall

Tried the Nvidia driver, installed using the Additional Drivers panel.  Didn't like it much; the CPU seemed to overheat more and the brightness controls stopped working. Also selecting a second display is a pain using that horrible NVidia settings thing.

So wanted to disabled it again.. problem is, UBuntu is then stuck in either 640x480 or 800x600 (second time I tried to install it back and then remove again).

How can I get this back the way it was?  The original Ubuntu drivers worked just fine, allowing me to run Unity and games properly.   I tried a xserver-xorg reconfigure but this didn't do anything. (No xorg.conf file either).

This is on a Lenovo Thinkpad T410i

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check if your `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` package is still installed? This is what it should be using (if not the NVidia binary driver). `dpkg -l xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` should have a line at the end starting `ii` if it's installed.

Comment: Thanks;  this doesn't solve the problem.  The Nouveau driver was still installed.  To be sure I removed it using the --purge option and then installed it again.

I get teh right resolution now but still I get random behavior of the display: flashes, flickering, random artifacts appearing and disappearing everywhere.

Comment: Update:  This is what I'm looking at currently; note the strange artifacts; these jump all over the place when I move a window.

incm.info/images/screenshot1.png

incm.info/images/screenshot2.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50617/how-can-i-remove-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your nouveau driver is not black-listed.

I had the same problem as you after installing the NVIDIA driver manually and removing it after not enjoying it.

You need to take a look in your /etc/modprobe.d folder. You may well find a file named something like "nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf". You will need to be root to delete this so fire up a terminal and punch in:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf
```

Obviously change this to whatever your file is called, if different. After that reboot and you should be good to go! I didn't use the restricted driver installer though, I downloaded the driver straight from NVIDIA so the file may be different or the lines:

```
blacklist nouveau

options nouveau modeset=0
```

May well be in a different file, so have a nosey around the modprobe.d folder.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Worked with 15.10 also. I had blacklisted nouveau in 4 different files in `/etc/modprobe.d/` so used `grep -rl "nouveau" /etc/modprobe.d`, removed them all blacklisting entries, rebooted and high resolution was back :)

Answer (score 4):

i've removed nvidia drivers and had the same low resolution on one of monitors.
surprisingly it helped to delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

Comment: yep, this worked: sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf~

Answer (score 1):

if your laptop has another onboard vga, use it instead of nvidia card...

Use bumblebee to solve the problem... it will automatically diagnose and solve your probs.

steps:
open terminat and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

for more instructions https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Upgrading-on-Ubuntu#wiki-install

Comment: Thanks;  this doesn't solve the problem.  The Nouveau driver was still installed.  To be sure I removed it using the --purge option and then installed it again.

I get teh right resolution now but still I get random behavior of the display: flashes, flickering, random artifacts appearing and disappearing everywhere.

Comment: I added the repository and it shows in my /etc/apt/sources.d directory, but it cannot find the bumblebee or bumblebee-nvidia package.

Comment: Update:  I don't think the nouveau driver is being used.. I removed xserver-xorg-video-nouveau and then restarted LightDM, and it behaves exactly the same.  Potentially some other driver is being used?  It's pretty unusable right now, I'm looking at screen-soup. ;) It takes a lot of clicking to get to this text box in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

I have a w510. unity(ubuntu 14.4) hangs intermittently.

I installed the bumblebee software and that made it worse.

Xorg would fail to start completely. I then tried a lot of things, installed `nvidia-331`, reinstalled the nouveau driver(which was the initial issue with the intermittent hangs).

The solution above worked for me. It turns out, the `bumblebee` stuff made a `bumblebee.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` which black listed nouveau and nvidia drivers. I removed the file, rebooted. then installed `nvidia-331`, rebooted (a `lightdm` would prbably do the trick too) and all is well again. :)

cheers

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove bumblebee` got rid of the blacklisted `nouveau` driver. After making sure I had `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` installed, I rebooted into full resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE:

`cd /etc/X11/`

`sudo rm xorg.conf`

Now you should be back to the previous nouveau configuration.