# 18.04 Cog not visible on login screen, can't boot with Wayland

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, wayland

For a piece of Windows-software I'm running in Mono, I need the display to be rendered with Wayland as X11 does not show everything correctly. I'm running two virtual machines with Ubuntu 18.04; one has the cog so I can login with Wayland, the other doesn't.

I've been comparing the gnome-session files and files in the gdm3 folder, but nothing seems to be different between the two machines.

Is there a way to restore the cog in the login screen? Or even better, is there a way to set Wayland as default for my virtual machines? If I can set it with a simple batch-script or settings file I'd be really happy.

p.s.: I've set snapshots during development of the Mono application, and even the earliest snapshot of the machine without the cog already missed it.

**EDIT:**
I found the issue, see my answer below. I'd still like to know how to switch to Wayland through a terminal command, as that would help out with automating installations for clients.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at configuration differences between my virtual machines, it seems this was caused by setting the video card drivers to the ones supplied in the VirtualBox Guest Additions ISO. Setting the drivers to "do not use device" in the "Software & Updates" program made the cog appear again. Both virtual machines had guest additions installed for copy-paste abilities between the host and guests, but only one of them had opted for the proprietary drivers for the video card.

Comment: This put me on the right track - but for me it was Nvidia drivers. I switched back to nouveau - I also had to remove Nvidia's blacklisting: https://askubuntu.com/a/158673/762941 - and then after a reboot had the cog back.