# How do I revert from the Nvidia driver to the unrestricted driver?

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove nVidia driver and go back to Nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau)

Installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a Gateway GT 5628 with a NVIDIA GeForce 8500 GT graphics processor.  Was working fine until I attempted to update the driver; now, after boot I get a blank/black screen.

How can I revert back to the unrestricted driver from a terminal?