# how to revert to default video driver from nvidia driver?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu

i downloaded the nvidia driver, and it seems to be messing things up. webcam programs dont work, blender isnt working. i need to revert to the default one.

Any help!?

this one doesnt make any since to me. [How do I revert from the Nvidia driver to the unrestricted driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97129/how-do-i-revert-from-the-nvidia-driver-to-the-unrestricted-driver)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable it in System Settings > Addition Drivers

Otherwise you can do it on the command line like this:

```
sudo jockey-text -d xorg:nvidia_current
```