# How do I remove Nvidia drivers and revert to nouveau (12.04)?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I'd like to give the new nouveau drivers a try. When I try a Ubuntu live distro, they work pretty flawlessly, but I don't seem to be able to use them correctly on my installed system.
What I do is remove Nvidia drivers from the Additional drivers utility and reboot, but what I get is no 3D acceleration and low resolution on my monitor. What am I doing wrong?
I wonder if I might have broken something when I messed up with grub trying to fix the infamous plymouth splash screen...

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

OP probably solved his problem but for future reference.

If you have tested various versions of nvidia drivers using jockey, it will just revert to whatever version of nvidia you have on your computer. You must continuously remove drivers on jockey until all versions are grayed out.

If you're stuck on command line, there is a command line jockey that can be started by `jockey-text`. Type `jockey-text --help` to see the list of options. You need to work with it as su (sudo) in order to disable/enable drivers.

Finally, you must remove xorg config file i.e. `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` since nvidia settings in it will most likely clash with nouveau and can prevent X from starting.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the nouveau drivers are blacklisted?

See if it something in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf or in one of the others in /etc/modprobe.d/

So, if there is, uninstall NVidia drivers, remove the blacklist nouveau line in the blacklist file(s) and reboot. Perhaps that would do the trick?

Comment: Nouveau drivers are blacklisted as long as nvidia drivers are installed. When i remove them, the blacklist nouveau lines disappear too, so that's not the case. Otherwise I wouldn't get any graphics at all, right?

Comment: I assume you have searched around - but there was some info in this http://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau?rq=1

Comment: I have. Nothing useful there. The point is: why do I get an ideal setup out of the box when I boot a live distro? It means there's something messed up in my system no matter if nvidia drivers are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me like charm, I got an oldie HP TX2000 and reinstalled several times because nothing seem to work, finally I found this:

```
sudo jockey-text -d xorg:nvidia_current
```

reference:
[how to revert to default video driver from nvidia driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148668/how-to-revert-to-default-video-driver-from-nvidia-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of removing them try following (it worked superb on my Ubuntu, however I cannot guarantee it will also work for you). Download drivers from nVidia website. Install additional drivers in jockey, after reboot remove them, and without reboot install downloaded drivers.