# Cannot properly boot into Ubuntu after installation of Nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, graphics, login, boot-failure

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Everything was fine until I did a fresh install of a proprietary driver for NVIDIA, using the "Additional drivers" utility. After having restarted my computer, I cannot access to my session as usual anymore.

Different things can happen:

- It starts under Ubuntu GNU GRUB with Linux 3.2.0-26-generic-pae, and it looks like a terminal, I can log in and all. `startx` gives me weird colored patterns on the screen and keeps frozen.
- It freezes immediately with the weird patterns, or with just a purple screen and my cursor after showing the "Ubuntu" login purple screen.
- Or it shows the usual login screen, but completely deformed, and unusable.

I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current` to fix my problem, but it didn't work.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: I know this may not very helpful. But My general recommendation is not to upgrade working graphics driver, unless you see problems.

Comment: You're right, I will be careful about that in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try removing your freshly installed Nvidia driver and go back to the open-source driver, Nouveau.
Log in to the command line interface of Ubuntu, launch `sudo apt-get install nouveau-firmware` (just in case) then follow the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/12941/5592:

> To reconfigure xorg.conf, type the following command:
>
> `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`
>
> Go following the screen steps, answering the wizard questions and you
>   should able to restore or reconfigure to previous **Nouveau** state.

After that, if this solved your problem, you will probably have a very low resolution. So launch the "Displays" utility from the Dash home and adjust your resolution accordingly to fit your screen the best.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem. Solved like this:

1. Boot as normal and get to login screen
2. press Ctrl + Alt + F1
3. Login with your username and password.
4. type **sudo stop lightdm** and press enter, stops X11
5. type **sudo apt-get purge nvidia*** and press enter -clears all nvidia items
6. type **sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau** and press enter- will install this package or tell you if it is already there.
7. type **sudo reboot**

this got me back up and running (although no icons in unity launcher - since need correct graphic drivers) check **system settings** to search for **Additional drivers** to see if this cab be addressed - although adding wrong drivers may cause the system to be faulty or freeze after login.

Comment: Helped me with incompatibilities between nvidia drivers and Linux 4.4/Ubuntu 16.04. Reverted to nouveau driver using your procedure. Thanks