# Low display resolution under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nvidia, resolution, nouveau

I had some problem after installing new drivers for Nvidia. After having followed the instructions answered to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163883/cannot-properly-boot-into-ubuntu-after-installation-of-nvidiadriver), I now only have the Nouveau open-source driver. I can have access to my desktop, but I'm stuck with a 640x480 (4:3) resolution. No other resolution is proposed in the dropdown list of the "Displays" utility.

I tried installing the two Nvidia drivers suggested in the "Additional Drivers" utility, but each one broke my display again.

Now that I have reverted back to Nouveau again, what should I do to get a higher resolution ?

Answer (score 0):

Press the Super key (formerly known as Windows key) to launch the Dash home and search for "Displays".
You will be presented with a roughly quarter of the displays' app window.
Navigate to the workspaces switcher in the launcher.
Now you will see the app in its full glory.
Go to the combobox with resolutions. (Somewhere near the center)
Select something higher and find the OK/Apply button (I am not using unity right now)
(Use the workspace swicther again).
Press it and say that you are sure.
That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the workspaces switcher tip, but actually, I cannot change anything in the combo box. It only proposes the 640x480 resolution, and nothing else.

Comment: I don't know how to help you in that case.Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try install binary version :) . Download the driver : http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us
File NVIDIA-xxx.run

Go to login screen. press ctrl+alt+f6 .login using ur username. and type in console after login:  sudo service lightdm stop, press ctrl+alt+f6 again. and go to ur download file. example if u put driver NVIDIA-xxx.run in /home/user/Downloads go to the folder with cmd: cd /home/user/Downloads . and type : sudo ./NVIDIA-xxx.run follow the instructions. Sometimes the warning will appears tells u must block nouveau and reboot pc first. just select Yes. and reboot.. and try again the instructions above.