# Unable to remove Multiple Nvidia Drivers Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda

There were multiple drivers installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, so I was unable to run OpenCL programs. I therefore did `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*` to start all over again.

However when I do  `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` It still returns: NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module 352.63 Sat Nov 7 21:25:42 PST 2015.

Any ideas on how to remove all these drivers? (304.131, 352.39, 352.63) from my system?

Thanks.

Edit : I also did `sudo apt-get remove --purge cuda*`, `sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall` and i'm still having the same issues.

Moreover dmesg|grep NVRM gives the output:

```
[ 10.206595] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 0000:01:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1380)
[ 10.206595] NVRM: installed in this system is not supported by the 304.131
[ 10.206595] NVRM: NVIDIA Linux driver release. Please see 'Appendix
[ 10.206595] NVRM: A - Supported NVIDIA GPU Products' in this release's
[ 10.206595] NVRM: README, available on the Linux driver download page
[ 10.206595] NVRM: at www.nvidia.com.

[ 10.206744] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
[ 10.206745] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
[ 18.076754] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 0000:01:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1380)
[ 18.076754] NVRM: installed in this system is not supported by the 304.131
[ 18.076754] NVRM: NVIDIA Linux driver release. Please see 'Appendix
[ 18.076754] NVRM: A - Supported NVIDIA GPU Products' in this release's
[ 18.076754] NVRM: README, available on the Linux driver download page
[ 18.076754] NVRM: at www.nvidia.com.

[ 18.076960] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
[ 18.076961] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
[ 18.130159] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 0000:01:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1380)
[ 18.130159] NVRM: installed in this system is not supported by the 304.131
[ 18.130159] NVRM: NVIDIA Linux driver release. Please see 'Appendix
[ 18.130159] NVRM: A - Supported NVIDIA GPU Products' in this release's
[ 18.130159] NVRM: README, available on the Linux driver download page
[ 18.130159] NVRM: at www.nvidia.com.

[ 18.130394] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
[ 18.130395] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
[2599693.694878] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module 352.63 Sat Nov 7 21:25:42 PST 2015
[2601583.725270] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 352.39, but
[2601583.725270] NVRM: this kernel module has the version 352.63. Please
[2601583.725270] NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
[2601583.725270] NVRM: components have the same version.
```

Comment: Dis you reboot after the uninstall of the drivers ? If not do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 (immediately after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04), X11 errored on launch similarly, with other versions of the Nvidia driver:

nvidia api mismatch the nvidia kernel module has version 340.96 but this nvidia driver component has version 304.131

I got a working X11 desktop through the following steps:

```
sudo aptitude remove nvidia-340 nvidia-304
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
reboot # (into low-res X11)
```

Unity dash/launcher --> Additional Drivers --> enable proprietary Nvidia-340

reboot again

Answers to the following question were helpful:
[Cannot properly boot into Ubuntu after installation of Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163883/cannot-properly-boot-into-ubuntu-after-installation-of-nvidia-driver)

Comment: For more recent upgrades, I've removed the nvidia driver beforehand. It can be re-installed afterward.

Answer (score 0):

after you run "sudo apt-get remove" run the following command;
sudo apt-get autoremove. This command will remove all unnecessary installation files. Try that to see if those folders gets removed.

Comment: That didn't remove the drivers. They are still appearing with the above mentioned commands.