# Error loading operating system - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, error-handling

Someone knows how can i resolve this problem?

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here: 
[Cannot properly boot into Ubuntu after installation of Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163883/cannot-properly-boot-into-ubuntu-after-installation-of-nvidia-driver)

If you cannot login to tty (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>),
 You may load you system by [RecoveryMode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

Comment: Instead of posting answers that mainly link to a different question on Ask Ubuntu, you should flag this question as duplicate of the other. And even if it would not be an exact duplicate, this post still is rather a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hold shift at the booting up, then you will come to the boot grub. There you'll see the word "quiet splash". Remove this and insert "nomodeset". Hope that helps you. Regards