# Remove proprietary Nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I manually installed the lastest Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 12.10 using the files directly from the Nvidia website. Long story short, they don't work, I have an extremely low resolution, and need to go back to nouveau. I can get to the terminal by re-logging in after holding down Ctrl-Alt-F1, how do I purge the proprietary drivers and go back to nouveau?

Comment: Have you tried the Nvidia drivers available from the restricted repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove nVidia driver and go back to Nouveau](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigate to the directory you downloaded the `.run` from, then do:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.60.run --uninstall
```

If you have a different version, obviously, change the name.  Now do:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

That last `rm` might fail; if it does, don't worry about it.  It's just to ensure that if Nvidia installed a custom `xorg.conf`, you got it out of there.

Finally,

```
sudo reboot
```

EDIT:  Whoops, didn't see the "from the Nvidia website."  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, the resolutions fixed but the unity bar is gone

Comment: I had something like that. I found that gnome worked (in a 2D mode) and that by installing xserver-xorg-video-nouveau unity worked again.