# Problems using VMware and VBox with Utopic 14.10

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, 14.10

When I installed Virtual box it would not run a machine. Same problem as encountered previously of it missing vboxdrv. Old fixes didnt work.

VMWare won't install as kernel headers do not match.

Can anyone help~?
Thanks

Comment: I also encountered this. In my case apparently, when virtualbox (vb) was updated the extension pack wasn't that caused vb to crash. So I removed vb completely. downloaded the latest version and the latest extension pack and installed both. After that my old vdi worked just fine! Hope this helps. A

Comment: What is the error message you get for the kernel errors with VMWare?

Comment: @CharlesGreen It told me that it couldn't find kernel header 3.13.0-37-generic and that if it was under a different directory. Then gave me an option to browse to find it.

Comment: @TomBucknall Have you tried `sudo apt-get install build-essential  linux-headers-``uname -r``

Comment: @TomBucknall  Code in comments is difficult - the "uname -r" needs to have backticks around it when entered into a command line.  This expands unto the version number , so the command becomes `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-3.13.0-37`

Comment: @CharlesGreen It says: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: @TomBucknallI should have read more carefully - as of Ubuntu 14.10, you should be on kernel 3.16, not 3.13.  Can you enter the command `uname -r` and verify that you are running the current kernel?

Comment: @CharlesGreen It says that I am on 3.13

Comment: @TomBucknall  Interesting.  And the command `lsb_release -a`

Comment: @CharlesGreen No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.10
Release: 14.10
Codename: utopic

Comment: Did you recently upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10?  Somehow your system is stuck on an older kernel version

Comment: @CharlesGreen Nope, I installed 14.04 then recently 14.10 when it prompted the upgrade. I did have a little problem with booting to a black screen (I upgraded nvidia) and the fix for that may have something to do with it.

Comment: @TomBucknall Will post in answer - askubuntu is complaining about extended conversations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel in use is 13.13.0-37, but should be 13.16 for Utopic.

My suggestion for attempting to fix this would be as follows:

Backup important data...

Remove the Nvidia drivers, as they may be a problem when upgrading kernels.  They can be reinstalled after kernel upgrade

Attempt to do a distribution upgrade:  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

reboot

Check to see if the kernel has been update `uname -r` - kernel should be 3.16.0-24

Reinstall Nvidia drivers if desired

Reinstall VMWare

Comment: How do I remove the nvidia drivers in terminal. (sorry if this has an obvious answer)

Comment: This link may have your answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau

Comment: @TomBucknall  One question - did you ever customize your grub file?

Comment: I fixed the problem radically by a complete reset of the computer. Basically wiped everything and started again. Thanks anyways

Comment: I won't say I haven't done the same myself, once or twice!

Answer (score 0):

*Thank's to Charles Greens's answer, Next time when I installed VMware Player I followed this:*

**VMware Player 7.0.0 Installation**

First of all, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

To install VMware Player 7.0.0 under Ubuntu 14.10 or older, run simply these commands from the Terminal:

```
mkdir ~/VMware && cd ~/VMware 

wget -c http://goo.gl/A9LHQv -O VMware-Player-7.0.0.x86_64.bundle.tar

tar -xvf VMware-Player-7.0.0.x86_64.bundle.tar

chmod +x VMware-Player-7.0.0-2305329.x86_64.bundle 

sudo sh VMware-Player-7.0.0-2305329.x86_64.bundle
```

Source: http://dothisbest.com/how-to/install-vmware-player-7-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-10/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by uninstalling the virtualbox installed in software center. Then     install the deb package from [official site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).