# Ubuntu installed fine, but I have three monitors hooked up to my PC and no screen

Tags: 15.10, multiple-monitors

This is all after a fresh install of 15.10 on my x99 Sabertooth, 2 x gtx970 in sli, 5820k intel processor,... and so forth.

1. I've got my main monitor hooked up to display port, second monitor hooked up to DVI and third HDMI. The only one that works is the DVI (television) monitor I've got hooked up.
2. And when it's hooked up and running I am given no mouse cursor, possibly because I have two mice and two keyboards hooked up.
3. When I try to activate the restricted drivers for my GTX970 SLI, it works for a second then goes back to where it started.
   I'm receiving error messages from boot up on Ubuntu,...

Sounds like I'm a little bias against Ubuntu.  I liked those old days when I used crappy computers and managed to get it running, but even then it was difficult.  So, yeah if anyone has any suggestions please send them my way

UPDATE:  The powered off all other monitors, and still nothing.  Powered on the one that works, and couldn't read error message...  still haven't unplugged the other mouse-but I'm lazy I'll try that in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe revert back to nouveau video drivers until you are able to boot to the gui? This link should help: [Remove nVidia driver and go back to Nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/q/12937/509657)

**Edit: Are you able to use the keyboard at all? If not, my answer won't help.... Also, could you make an edit saying what the error messages you're getting at boot are?**

Comment: I haven't altered the drivers, when I go to "apply" or "okay" the restricted drivers, it sets it back to whatever it was initially on.  I am able to navigate with the keyboard.  And sort of with the mouse, I just have no cursor so mouse usage is nearly impossible.

Comment: @daniel Have you tried booting with just one monitor, one mouse, and one keyboard attached? I'm not really sure what the issue could be.. Also, what error messages is it giving you?