# Unable to login in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my brand new hardware about a month ago (Intel I7 6700k, Asus Pro Gaming mini ITX motherboard and Nvidia GTX950 graphics card). Things have been going mostly well, however The pic repeatedly comes up with a `16.04 internal error, try restarting your computer`. When I look at the details it talks about compiz has crashed and Nvidia drivers. Firefox also repeatedly crashes, but everything else to date has worked perfectly.

So this evening I tried to correct the problem by upgrading the driver. I looked in the Software and Updates section, and it said it was using the reccommended driver (Nvidia 3.61.42) however when I looked online, a newer driver was available. I followed instructions posted on a forum page here, doing the install using `apt-get` in a terminal window. BANG. Now I cannot log in at all!! The machine takes me to a guest login, which I have never used, and insists on a password I don't have (including leaving it blank). There is no option to use my standard username/login.

I am able to get to a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, or similar combination) but it wants a login and user name that does not exist. I know, I have read all over the place how this is the login you establish when you first install Ubuntu, well I can tell you that my standard login DOES NOT WORK! I have been logging in without incident for a month, but now using this same login, I can't get in, and I don't have a guest login either (as stated, never ever used)

So short of re-installing and spending untold hours re-configuring software etc. what do I do?

I have also tried the grub login as well. I can get into the GRUB menu, select a version with RECOVER. But when I select to use a low res graphics option, it just locks up. And the drive, though I can access it through the root option in GRUB appears to be read only, so I can't run something like DCONF reset as suggested here on the web. It just tells me everything is read only!

Frustrated and out of time this evening. Hope somebody has some answers.
Regards,
Graham

Comment: I see two possible problems. Login doesn't work because starting X after login crashes or maybe your regional settings somehow changed and you type in wrong password. I would check keyboard settings, remove NVidia and try to login and then restore NVidia again. (http://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau, http://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

Comment: Thanks for assistance. Ultimately I had to reinstall Ubuntu. I am almost certain it was the version of Nvidia driver that I installed that broke everything. Why though a video driver should completely corrupt everything (including ability to login) is beyond me. No doubt somebody a lot more knowledgeable may have had better luck, but I exhausted all options and after many hours, decided on a re-install.

Comment: And I can tell you with absolute certainty that even my login name/password did not work. It kept telling me (whether using a terminal login, or GUI ("safe mode") that my password was incorrect, yet it wasn't. I could therefore find no means of recovery.

Comment: This is why I feel it is very necessary for Ubuntu to have a restore point capability  similar to windows. This would save thousands of amateurs like me from the headache of a full re-install, not to mention saving hours of needless headaches for the Ubuntu gurus out there that have to keep answering/diagnosing small questions all the time. Just a thought.

Comment: Similar problem here. There seems to be a broad issue with Ubuntu 16.04 running on Intel i7 chipsets. System updates already wreck Ubuntu in two of the computers I work on. My best advice is to stick with Ubuntu 14.04 for now.