# Ubuntu 16.04 won't properly wake up from suspend

Tags: 16.04, grub2, suspend, wakeup

I've been trying to fix this problem for a while but I can't find a solution. The laptop goes to sleep without any problem but when I open it up again the fan starts working and the screen goes on, but it's all black. This is my grub file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb1)"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Also I'm using my graphic card driver:
[image: Additional Drivers]

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`? If this doens't work you can easily reinstall them with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-384`. Since when do you have this problem?

Comment: I tried. When I open the lid the screen doesn't even go on.
I've had this problem for a few months so since I'm on dual boot I just started using Windows again. Now I want to change back to Ubuntu but this is really annoying me. Have you got any other idea?

Comment: Hmmm... I know this happening with nvidia drivers... I had the problem myself but purging solved the problem. From what you said, if after removing the nvidia drivers you aren't able to make the graphics work, I suppose that means you haven't got any graphics driver installed. Maybe: https://askubuntu.com/a/12941/742966