# How do you properly install NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gpu, 18.10

After I tried to install my GPU driver, my Ubuntu wouldn't boot. How do I install my driver correctly? Every time I try after I restart my system my Ubuntu won't boot. I'd like to know how to properly install my GPU NVIDIA driver. Thanks.

Comment: As noted below, purge, not remove is needed to rid your system of old configuration files. e.g.  sudo  apt-get purge nvidia-driver-390.  (Equivalent to apt-get remove --purge ...)

Comment: I "purged" my Nvidia driver to try and boot my computer, but it's still trying to use the Nvidia driver I don't have. Do you know how to get it to boot using Ubuntu's driver?

Comment: List any remaining nvidia packages with dpkg -l nvidia*  (only the ones starting with "ii" ). Purge those packages too.  Can you log into the guest session?  If so, there may be leftover nvidia config in one of your hidden dot files (files whose first character is a period).

Comment: I can't log on to the gust session, but I'll try to purge the remaining packages.

Comment: "Failed to read file 'nvidia*'"

Comment: You can edit the question to add information instead of adding comments, which might get removed.  On my 18.04 system, the expected output (for no packages) of dpkg -l nvidia* would be dpkg-query: no packages found matching nvidia*   What exact command did you give to get that "Failed to read file"  output?

Comment: Dpkg -I nvidia*

Answer (score 1):

- Run on Terminal `software-properties-gtk`
- Go to "Additional Driver" tab.
- Select NVIDIA Driver and click on apply changes.

[image: NVIDIA]

- When completed reboot.

Comment: I tried but it wouldn't boot.

Comment: I think your previous installations of NVIDIA drivers are causing the problem. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau) and try the GUI again.

Comment: I can't boot Ubuntu at all, I'm stuck in recovery mode. So I can't do that.