# August update of major Linux version in Jammy 22.04 caused complete loss of NVIDIA driver setup

Tags: nvidia, updates, video, .desktop

August 3-4 Ubuntu offered an update. It was not at all clear going in that it was a major version change, being a jump in major Linux version from 5.19 to 6.2.
At first it booted as usual with a notification in 'system tray' that reported broken packages. I followed the suggestion to remove and reinstall those packages and was left with a box that will only boot into command line mode.
Furthermore, reversion to previous version fails in the same way: no NVIDIA drivers available where they used to be.

Using recovery mode menu to run dpkg tells me there are no packages available for NVIDIA GeForce video card, and libglmesa.  Also Zoom fwiw.

I would prefer not to start from scratch here. Anyone have any helpful pointers on how to patch this back up?

Date: 4 August 2023

Event: Ubuntu driven auto upgrade
From Linux 5.19 to 6.2 in jammy 22.04LTS

Video card: NVIDIA GeForce

Drivers missing:
NVIDIA 470 series, and others

### Answer (h/t Rinzwind)

Reinstalling the desktop:

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Applied at the command prompt in the newer version, it restored the use of the desktop on both the updated version with Linux 6.2 and the previous version with Linux 5.19.

Jammy is unjammed!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What graphics card?

Comment: "*major upgrade being a jump in major Linux version from 5 to 6*" around August 3-4 suggests a point release of Ubuntu 22.04. But much better to so specify in your question -- our deduction might be wrong.

Comment: Linux went from 5.19 to 6.2  It was Friday 8/4 for me.

Comment: you are not alone. see the diff. topics already on AU. several have what appear to be working solutions

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind ... Any from this year?

Comment: All are from this month ;-)

Comment: "and was left with a box that will only boot into command line mode."  most seen suggestion:  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` (change ubuntu ofc. to what you use ;))  Not sure what happend though; the topics have all not a lot of detail (only "i don't get a desktop"). Maybe a bug in systemd where it is told to pick server or desktop mode. A bug with the nvidia driver is likely: key ingredient to get a working desktop.  What really is strange is that I do not see anything about it in the mailing lists :P

Comment: Bless you Rinzwind.

Comment: Reinstalling the desktop worked on the new Linux 6.2 version, and the same beautifully simple brute force solution applied once to the newer version restored the desktop in the older version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this ha been resolved.
Standard Nouveau drivers were the only option for my system.

Could be that you're Nvidia card is not supported in the update/kernel revision.
I have an LGR580 and the Nvidia GT130M graphics card has no support past 5.15 I believe.

Standard Nouveau drivers were the only thing that worked, unfortunately.
Try rolling back the video driver from terminal.
You should be able to boot to repair.

Please check out this post to switch back to the Nouveau driver from boot terminal...

[Remove nVidia driver and go back to Nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ragu. The restoral of the desktop has allowed the PC to function well for a couple days now.  I believe the update with underlying Linux upgrade was the issue, it left many packages unselected and dysfunctional.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened here.  Fix was:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Then logout and back in.